# How to implement shadow in Android?

Tags: android, shadow

My UX designer has provided me with an elegant design and exported it as an Xd file. For shadows of some elements, Xd gives me below information:

```
Shadow color: #101F400D
X: 0dp
Y: 3dp 
Blur: 10dp
```

How can I create this layout in android with the above information?

**Note:** `elevation` is not what I want!

[image: this is what i want to code]

Comment: You can use cardview and then set elevation to that cardview else you can use layer-list to create a background drawable with shadow effect

Comment: it's hard and bad final result without elevation. you have to create a drawable shape and use it as shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cardView or [Material design cardview](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-card-view/) to get the shadow effect

If you want to follow the guideline of material design you have to implement dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha02'
```

You can use material cardview as shown below

```
 <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardElevation="4dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite">
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a nine patch image to achieve this. Create a nine patch image using any tool like this - https://inloop.github.io/shadow4android/

Then, set this image as background to your view.